# Check validity of "windows shorcuts"

Tags: windows, shortcuts, desktop

Is there any simple, automatable  method of check for a .lnk file validity?

I mean I got a couple of directories whith these shorcuts to apps, and the only way I know if the executable file stills where the link file points, is to look if the icon appears to be ok... weird.

So I want some sort of command or light tool (oss will be greatly appreciated) to check and perhaps delete any "broken .lnk" in a directory

Thanks!

Comment: Are you taking about symbolic-links (also known as junction points) or shortcuts?

Comment: shorcuts, .lnk files. I wrote that 'symbolic links' betwen quotes because I'm a linux guy and didn't know that new windows OSes support a kind of s-links.

Comment: @theist - This would be a good point to remove `symbolic links` from your question if your asking about `shortcuts` since `symbolic links` do exists in the Windows world.

Comment: @Ramhound I changed the tags from symbolic-links to shorcuts. And that other reference in text is quoted, meaning 'not exactly' the rest of the text and the title talks about Shorcuts or .lnk files. Do you think question isn't clear enough?

Comment: @theist - I still think you shouldn't mention symbolic links since your asking about shortcuts, and shortcuts, are NOT symbolic links.

Answer (score 2):

Try **ChkLnks.exe** by Microsoft.  [How To Clean Broken Shortcuts In Windows 7](http://www.technetsavvy.com/2011/08/how-to-clean-broken-shortcuts-on.html)

There are some free apps as well to do the same. [Apps to get rid of Broken Shortcuts](http://techdows.com/2010/09/4-free-apps-to-get-rid-of-broken-shortcuts-from-your-computer.html)

Comment: Or if you prefer using scripts...this article depicts working with shortcuts using Windows Powershell.   http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/working-shortcuts-windows-powershell

Comment: Yeah @Gh0sT . In fact in my home box this is fixed with a perl script runing with ActiveState's perl under windows... but I was looking for a 'user' solution :). I'll try your recomendation.

Answer (score 1):

MS’s FixKit can check common ones for you automatically...

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/system_maintenance_for_windows/en-gb

Comment: uff strange tool. Once downloaded present a long and unuseful list of "things this can do" After select one who match my problem, it opens IE to download a long named exe. And asks to reboot... If anything of these wouldn't come from MS sites I will think that I've installed some sort of trojan. To be continued...

Comment: After restart seems like that tool can fix several problems I had and I dindn't know, And my broken links still there.